# Animacion aleatoria en android

Tags: android, animación

Buenas estoy tratando de hacer una animacion usando un XML y animation-list, me sale todo correcto pero el problema que tengo es que quiero que el orden de la animación sea siempre distinto  cada vez que se inicie es activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
xmlns:android= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot= "false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice1"
    android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice2"
    android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice3"
    android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice4"
    android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice5"
    android:duration="200" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/dice6"
    android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Ese seria el xml que uso, solo las 6 imagenes que uso, y a continuación pondre como inicio la animacion en el activity

```
private AnimationDrawable animacion;
private AnimationDrawable animacion2;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.pantalla_partida);


    dado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Dado);
    dado2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Dado2);

    animacion = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.animacion);
    animacion2 = (AnimationDrawable) ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.animacion);
    dado.setImageDrawable(animacion);
    dado2.setImageDrawable(animacion2);
```

Este seria todo el codigo, si es posible también querria saber si es posible saber que frame actual tiene la animación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes hacer servir este ejemplo.

Creas un xml con tus arrays.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<integer-array name="imagenesArray">
    <item>@drawable/uno</item>
    <item>@drawable/dos</item>
    <item>@drawable/tres</item>
</integer-array>
</resources>
```

Luego en el main haces lo siguiente:

```
   private TypedArray miArray;
   private int numeroAleatorio;
   private ImageView imagen;
   private Drawable drawable;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imagen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagen);

    //Le digo cual es el array donde tiene que buscar.
    miArray = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.imagenesArray);

    //Creamos una instancia de la clase Random.
    final Random random = new Random();

    //Usamos la clase math para encontrar un numero aleatorio, de nuestro    array.
    numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * miArray.length());

    //Obtengo el objeto drawable.
    drawable = miArray.getDrawable(numeroAleatorio);

    //Finalmente asignamos la imagen o el recurso.
    imagen.setBackground(drawable);

    //Mostramos el numero de la imagen en un toat.
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "La imagen es la : " + numeroAleatorio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
 }
}
```

Si quieres que cada vez que toques la imagen te haga un cambio añade un onClickListener a tu imagen.

```
   imagen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cambiaimagen();
        }
    });
}
```

Y dentro copias esta parte, si haces esto no olvides darle un imagen inicial a la imagen en el onCreate o no veras nada.

```
private void cambiaimagen() {
    //Usamos la clase math para encontrar un numero aleactorio, de nuestro array.
    numeroAleatorio = (int) (Math.random() * miArray.length());

    //Obtengo el objeto drawable.
    drawable = miArray.getDrawable(numeroAleatorio);

    //Finalmente asignamos la imagen o el recurso.
    imagen.setBackground(drawable);

    //Mostramos el numero de la imagen en un toat.
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "La imagen es la : " + numeroAleatorio, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    }
```

[image: Ejemplo de lo que verás en pantalla]

Gracias y saludos espero ayudarte.